# PDF is blank after Upload from ASP Classic

Tags: pdf, asp-classic

I am making an uploader for a page where I have to use ASP Classic and found Jacob "Beezle" Gilley's uploader and it is working, as long as it is a txt file. But the problem occurs when it's a pdf file or image, and i need to upload them.

The problem is that the example pdf file gets uploaded to its place but it is blank. I have edited in some of the original code since I need to have it UTF-8 encoded. Otherwise it is identical, and I will upload the edited code.

```
    Public Sub SaveToDisk(sPath)
    Dim oFS, oFile
    Dim oStream

    If sPath = "" Or FileName = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Mid(sPath, Len(sPath)) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

    Set oFS = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not oFS.FolderExists(sPath) Then Exit Sub

    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With oStream
    .Type = 2
    .Charset = "UTF-8"
    .Mode = 3
    .Open
    .WriteText RSBinaryToString(FileData)
    .SaveToFile sPath & FileName
    .Close
    End With
    Set oStream = Nothing
End Sub
```

How do I fix it, or can I even fix it? The RSBinaryToString method is credited to Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com which I found to help convert to UTF-8. Whitout this I cant even open the files.

Answer (score 0):

I found out an answer to my question.

```
    Public Sub SaveToDisk(sPath)
    Dim oFS, oFile
    Dim oStream
    Dim strText

    If sPath = "" Or FileName = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Mid(sPath, Len(sPath)) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

    Set oFS = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not oFS.FolderExists(sPath) Then Exit Sub

    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With oStream
    .Type = 2
    .Charset = "Windows-1252"
    .Mode = 3
    .Open
    .Position = 0
    .SetEOS
    .WriteText RSBinaryToString(FileData), 0
    .SaveToFile sPath & FileName, 2
    .Close
    End With
    Set oStream = Nothing
End Sub
```

Instead of using Charset = UTF-8 then use Windows-1252. Works like a charm.

Comment: Actually the use of charsets and strings to transport the PDF at all is wrong. PDFs are binary data, so there should be merely a byte array or something similar which is written without any charset settings interfering. Your currently working variant most likely merely fortunately encodes and decodes the data in a matching way (while it should not be encoded or decoded at all).